# Two-way look up (or is it HLookup) formula needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Grid]

I have the above grid in Excel..I would like to find a formula that would allow me to use the name in column A as a look up value, and return the value in Row 1 which is chosen by that person (i.e. a "1" in the column).. Like shown below:

[image: What I want]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula, say, in `I2` and grag it down:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$H$1,1,MATCH(1,B2:H2,0))
```

[image]

---

OR, if you have somewhere *unsorted* list of names and want to get choosen item, there is another formula:

`=INDEX($B$1:$H$1,1,MATCH(1,INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(J2,$A$2:$A$8,0)):INDEX($H$2:$H$8,MATCH(J2,$A$2:$A$8,0)),0))`

where your unsorted list of names started at `J2`. Write above formula in `K2` and drag it down as shown in image below:

[image]

Comment: went with =IFERROR(INDEX(List!$J$1:List!$Q$44,1,MATCH(1,List!J2:List!Q2,0)),"") in the end (I wanted the output on a different work sheet)

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to get the Item based on name, you can write:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$H$1;MATCH(1;OFFSET($B$2:$H$7;MATCH(I7;$A$2:$A$7;0)-1;0;1);0))
```

In this case you get the Item based on name in I7

Comment: `OFFSET` is [volatile function](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm). It's not a good way. It will make your formula recalculate each time _any cell on the sheet changed_

Comment: Thats why the offset function exists, it is not a good idea to use it. I think you should report to microsoft and ask then to remove this function from excel  :)

Comment: actually, in almost all cases, we can use `Index` instead `offset` :) see second formula in my answer